# Style adjacent selected list items using only CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to style a group of selected rows in a list (DIVs or ULs) so that they appear grouped by having custom styles on the first (i.e. border-top) and last row (i.e. border-bottom) of a group of selections? For example, in the below list, row 2,3,4 and 6 are selected:

```
--------------
| row 1      |
--------------
| *row 2*    |
| *row 3*    |
| *row 4*    |
--------------
| row 5      |
--------------
| *row 6*    |
--------------
| row 7      |
--------------
```

and the code would look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>row 1</li>
  <li class="selected">row 2</li>
  <li class="selected">row 3</li>
  <li class="selected">row 4</li>
  <li>row 5</li>
  <li class="selected">row 6</li>
  <li>row 7</li>
</ul>
```

I *could* use javascript and a secondary class name to differentiate the first and last selection of a group of selections, but I would prefer to do it with only the existing "selected" class name and pure CSS.

I tried the + selector, but it only got me so far. I could determine the first selected item of a group, but not the last. Without being able to look-ahead with a CSS selector, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: You can use nth-child and nth-last-child to select first and last child.
In your case: li:nth-child(1) {} to select "row 1" and li:nth-last-child(1) {} to select "row 7".

Comment: I don't need to know the first and last of all the rows. Only the groups of selected rows. first/last/nth-child pseudo classes won't completely help me.

Answer (score 1):

As a potential answer to my own question after a lot of fiddling with CSS, I came up with this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLZbRP

```
.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color: pink;
}

li.selected + li.selected {
  box-shadow: none;
}  
li:not(.selected) + li.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
li.selected + li:not(.selected) {
  box-shadow:inset 0 5px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

This is pretty close to exactly what I needed (with the shadows). It also has hover styles that work. The only thing it's missing that I haven't figured out yet is the left/right shadows. Adding them results in individual shadows beside each row, which doesn't look right.

Comment: I was actually going to suggest this. Kudos to you for thinking of it. For the left/right shadows, I'd suggest just straight hiding them (via multiple shadows and negative spread ([sample](https://conceptboard.github.io/box-shadow-spread-examples/))), and then using good ole' `border`s to solve them (since they'll handle themselves).

Comment: actually.... you could probably do it with `border`s entirely if you'd rather not spam shadows. Obviously, would depend on the exact effect you're trying to do.

Comment: How would you do it with borders entirely?

Comment: @abluejelly I'm curious how you would do this with borders.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive: [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/a1f3b32e2eba8c1c4807fbc061ebef1c). If you want me to put that as an answer lemme know, I'll formalize it. Oh, also, on this answer you'll want to add a `.selected:last-of-type` rule that puts a shadow below, otherwise if the selected is the last item it looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

## Not completely (yet)

Following code selects the first and last elements in each group of selected `li`s. Explanation: the first `.selected` that follows a `li` that is not `.selected`, and the first child if `.selected` are always the first `li` in a group of selected elements. For selecting the `li` that is the last one in a group, you could select the last element (if `.selected`), and see if it has a adjacent sibling that is not selected. If one of those matches, it is the last one in a group.

You can't select an element based on the elements after or inside it yet, but will be possible with a proposed CSS selector, [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), that is basically the solver of every good CSS selector problem. It is not compatible with any browser, but probably will be in the future. For future readers: if row 4 is blue, it is probably compatible with your browser.

```css
li.selected:first-child,
li:not(.selected) + li.selected {
  /* First of group of selection */
  color: red;
}

li.selected:last-child,
li.selected:not(:has(+li.selected)) {
  /* Last of group of selection */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>row 1</li>
  <li class="selected">row 2 (selected)</li>
  <li class="selected">row 3 (selected)</li>
  <li class="selected">row 4 (selected)</li>
  <li>row 5</li>
  <li class="selected">row 6 (selected)</li>
  <li>row 7</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:**
I didn't notice you said you knew about the `:has()`/lookahead selector. I'll leave it there for future readers, as it may be available by then.

Comment: And for completeness, you can view the [working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), or check out the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)